# Permutation Matrix - Distance to Identity

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Given a [permutation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix), I want to compute the minimum number of pairwise row swaps I need to make so that I end up with the identity.

An example:

$$\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\1 & 0& 0 & 0\\ 0&0&0 & 1\\0&1&0&0\end{pmatrix}\rightarrow\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0& 1 & 0\\ 0&0&0 & 1\\0&1&0&0\end{pmatrix}\rightarrow\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0& 1 & 0\\ 0&1&0 & 0\\0&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}\rightarrow\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 1& 0 & 0\\ 0&0&1 & 0\\0&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$

This permutation needed 3 swaps to return to identity. Note that it does not have to be adjacent rows for a swap to be allowed, even though this example only had those.

My reason for wanting to compute this is really because I want to know how many permutations require an *even* number of swaps, out of all the $n!$ possibilities. I was thinking that if I had a formula I might be able to derive this, or at worst brute force count all permutations for reasonable values of $n$.

Any help would be much appreciated!

**Edit**: I seem to have stumbled across a much harder (though interesting) problem while trying to show something that seems to be a known thing - that there are exactly $n!/2$ permutations requiring an even number of swaps. While I really appreciate the answer given to my original question (accepted as it does what I asked for), **I would really like a proof/explanation of *why* there are equal amounts of even/odd permutations?**

Comment: Exactly half of the $n!$ permutation matrices require an even number of swaps. These are the even permutations.

Comment: Your first question amounts to the computation of the number of inversions in your permetation. Please take a look at 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6523712/calculating-the-number-of-inversions-in-a-permutation

Comment: @Jean That's not right, the OP is allowing arbitrary transpositions. That's a more difficult number to compute than inversions. Much more difficult than how many require an even number.

Comment: @MikeEarnest Do you have/know a proof for this? It seems very correct (and is I guess), but both on Wikipedia and Wolfram Mathworld it's simply stated as fact. I'll be basing some results on this fact, and I would at the very least like to read _a_ proof before continuing... It might be obvious, but then it should be easy to point out why, right?

Comment: @Matt Samuel : I don't understand but I am ready to accept it : for example in the given matrix, there are 3 inversions and 3 operations are used. Could you give me a counterexample ?

Comment: @Jean Sure. If the swaps are not required to be adjacent, $\left(\begin{array}{ccc} 0&0&1\\0&1&0\\1&0&0\end{array}\right)$ only requires one swap, but it has 3 inversions.

Comment: @Bendik Regardless, you don't need to be able to compute the number of swaps to know that exactly $n! /2$ require an even number.

Comment: @Matt Samuel Undestood ! Thank you very much (I suppose that the $1$ in the last line is in position 1 not 3).

Comment: @Jean Yes, I have edited the comment since I posted it.

Comment: @Bendik The parity of the length of any sequence of swaps yielding the identity is always the same as the parity of the number of inversions, even if it isn't a minimal sequence of swaps and the swaps are not adjacent.

Comment: This is a very elementary fact for a mathematician, because it's covered early in a course on group theory. It's true because the set of permutations with an even number of inversions is a normal subgroup.

Comment: @MattSamuel I get that all of this is probably elementary for a mathematician, but for a mere mortal physicist like myself, things like  "It's true because the set of permutations with an even number of inversions is a normal subgroup." is just a prime example of a mathematician's non-answer answer. If it is so simple, how come we need to introduce entirely new concepts to explain them?

Comment: That's the thing, these are not new concepts. We're talking 19th century. Do you know about Lie groups?

Comment: @MattSamuel New as in new to me/most people. By that logic almost all math is old, but that certainly doesn't make it trivial. And no, no group theory background except occasionally stumbling into it here and there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To compute the number of swaps needed to make the identity, compute the number of cycles the permutation has. If the permutation has $k$ cycles, then the required number of swaps is $n-k$.

To see this, examine how swapping affects the cycle structure of a permutation. You can show that if you swap to elements in the same cycle, then that cycle will split into two, while if you swap two elements in different cycles, they will merge into one. Therefore, if you start with $k$ cycles and want to reach the identity which has $n$ cycles, it will takes $n-k$ swaps.

In your example, you permutation was a single cycle $1\to 3\to 2\to 4\to 1$, so the required number of swaps was $4-1=3$.

---

For example, consider the permutation 
\begin{matrix}
3&4&5&1&6&2
\end{matrix}
This is a single cycle, which in cycle notation is $(1\;\;4\;\;2\;\;6\;\;5\;\;3)$, because $1$ is placed in spot $4$, $4$ is placed in spot $2$, etc. Now, switch any two elements in this permutation, say, $4$ and $6$. The result is now
\begin{matrix}
3&6&5&1&4&2
\end{matrix}
Now the new cycle notation is $(1\;\;4\;\;5\;\;3)(2\;\;6)$, since $2$ and $6$ are switched, while $1$ is in spot $4$, $4$ is in spot $5$, etc. In other words, one cycle became two. If there were other disjoint cycles in this permutation, they would be unaffected.

Going in reverse, that is starting with the second permutation and switching $4$ and $6$ to get the first, we see two cycles merge into one.

Comment: This doesn't make sense. What about a transposition, which only requires $1$ but has a single cycle?

Comment: Are you counting fixed points as trivial cycles?

Comment: @MattSamuel Yes, fixed points are cycles of length $1$.

Comment: Thank you for this, this makes sense. Could you add an explanation for _why_ there are an equal amount of even and odd permutations? Or a link to such a thing?

Comment: @Bendik If $\alpha$ is an even permutation, then $(1\;\;2)\alpha$, the permutation given by switching $1$ and $2$ in $\alpha$, is an odd permutation. This correspondence is bijective, proving the number of even and odd permutations is the same.

Comment: So because _any_ swap from an even perm gives a unique odd perm, _and_ because the same holds for odd perms, the only way for both to be true is if there are an equal amount of even/odd perms in total? Alright, I think I've convinced myself suitably. Thanks!